# Shrinker already set to false still "Build-in class shrinker and multidex are not supported yet."

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-multidex

I'm working on an open source app which has several methods and updating the Support Design Library version results in engendering Multi-dex issue.

I enabled multi-dex following the official documentation but then I encountered this issue `Build-in class shrinker and multidex are not supported yet.`

The catch here is that both the `useProguard` as well as `minifyEnabled` properties are already set to false!

There are also some libraries being used in the app. Can it be the reason that those libraries use `Shrinker` and that's what causing it? What can be the potential resolution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to fixing after removing `productFlavors {}` block (which was empty in the app anyway) and the `useProguard False` statement in `release` block in `buildTypes`.

I still have no idea why I had to mess with `release` config to make changes in `debug`.